# how to do a left,right and mid of a string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

in a pandas dataframe how can I apply a sort of excel left('state',2) to only take the first two letters. Ideally I want to learn how to use left,right and mid in a dataframe too. So need an equivalent and not a "trick" for this specific example.

```
data = {'state': ['Auckland', 'Otago', 'Wellington', 'Dunedin', 'Hamilton'],
'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print df

     pop       state  year
 0  1.5    Auckland  2000
 1  1.7       Otago  2001
 2  3.6  Wellington  2002
 3  2.4     Dunedin  2001
 4  2.9    Hamilton  2002
```

I want to get this:

```
    pop       state     year  StateInitial
 0  1.5       Auckland    2000     Au
 1  1.7       Otago       2001     Ot
 2  3.6       Wellington  2002     We
 3  2.4       Dunedin     2001     Du
 4  2.9       Hamilton    2002     Ha
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

First two letters for each value in a column:

```
>>> df['StateInitial'] = df['state'].str[:2]
>>> df
   pop       state  year StateInitial
0  1.5    Auckland  2000           Au
1  1.7       Otago  2001           Ot
2  3.6  Wellington  2002           We
3  2.4     Dunedin  2001           Du
4  2.9    Hamilton  2002           Ha
```

For last two that would be `df['state'].str[-2:]`. Don't know what exactly you want for middle, but you can apply arbitrary function to a column with `apply` method:

```
>>> df['state'].apply(lambda x: x[len(x)/2-1:len(x)/2+1])
0    kl
1    ta
2    in
3    ne
4    il
```

Comment: Thanks @alko, I had tried the [-2:0] in an incorrect way earlier with syntex errors, your answer has fixed that for me.

Comment: I have another example where i am try to apply the first two digits of an 8 digit number. then i get the error. 'invalid index to scalar variable' how can i apply the above to take the last 2 numbers in 'year'?

Comment: @IcemanBerlin do you need result modulo 100 (that will be `0` for `2000` for example), or need to cast to string, to get `'100'` for the same `2000`?

Comment: basically what i have is week in this format 201302 as in week 2 of 2013. I am not sure if it is a string or integer in my dataframe. but i was trying to split out the last 2 digits so it would return in this example 02. I actually want to try and see what is the maximum month that belongs to the week. so 201302 would be January or 01. and week 201301 would be the max of dec 2012 and jan 2013 and thus be the latter and return 01.

Comment: @IcemanBerlin in this detail it is not so trivial to be answered in followup comments. I suggest you to start a new topic with this question (weeks to months conversion). Note that you can infer data type with something like `df['year'].dtype`.

Comment: ok will do. more related to this question though how could i split out the last two digits of the column 'year' would something close to this work df['yearInitial'] = df['year'].int[:2]

Comment: @IcemanBerlin No, str is for columns of string type. For int you have to convert to string with `df['year'].astype('str')` and proceed as in answer, or use numerical operations such as `df['year'] % 100`.

Comment: awesome this part worked well. df['week2dgts']  = df['Week'].astype('str').str[:2]

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the mid, probably a short cut code would be
        df['state'].str[3,5]

this will start from the 3rd character and give you the 3rd and 4th character of the string.

Comment: There is a typo here, should read str[3:5] rather than str[3,5]