# Get specific characters from string in DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, text-extraction

I have a Pandas DataFrame from an Excel file that I read in. I have a specific column in the data frame that contains strings in any of these forms:

```
22th/Dec if we receive order by 26/Sep
12th/Dec if we receive order by 26/Sep
10th/November if we receive order by 26th/Sep
```

I'm looking to grab the numeric date number (22 or 12 or 10 for example) and the string month name (Dec or November for example), so I'd like to create one variable that only grabs the day number and another that grabs the month name.

I could use a series of left/rights like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970279/how-to-do-a-left-right-and-mid-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe), but it's not that simple.  Sometimes the data might come as '9th' or '8th' in the beginning so the character count I place won't work there, unless I do some kind of 'if length > x, then' code. What's the cleanest way to grab specific characters into a new variable?

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame str.extract method takes regular expressions, which is what you want.

```
df['text_col'].str.extract(r'^(\d+)\S*/(\S+) ')
```

That will return a Dataframe with two columns containing your data.

Or to get better headers,

```
>>> df['text_col'].str.extract(r'^(?P<day>\d+)\S*/(?P<month>\S+) ')
  day     month
0  22       Dec
1  12       Dec
2  10  November
```