# Pandas column indexing strings

Tags: python, pandas

So I want to take only the first three characters of a pandas column and match them. This is what I have come up with but the implementation is incorrect:

```
df.loc[df[0:2] == 'x, y] = 'x'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to do a left,right and mid of a string in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970279/how-to-do-a-left-right-and-mid-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe/20970328)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, need `str` and define column for replacement if `df` is `DataFrame`, also for `x, y` there is `4` characters with whitespace:

```
df.loc[df['col'].str[:4] == 'x, y', 'col'] = 'x'

#another solution 
#df.loc[df['col'].str.startswith('x, y'), 'col'] = 'x'
```

If working with `Series`:

```
s[s.str[:4] == 'x, y'] = 'x'
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['x, y temp', 'sx, y', 'x, y', 's']})
print (df)
         col
0  x, y temp
1      sx, y
2       x, y
3          s

#if want replace substring
df['col1'] = df['col'].str.replace('^x\, y', 'x')

#if want set new value if condition
df.loc[df['col'].str[:4] == 'x, y', 'col'] = 'x'
print (df)
     col    col1
0      x  x temp <-col1 replace only substring
1  sx, y   sx, y
2      x       x
3      s       s
```